# Python : Ускорить запись на диск из файла в памяти.

Tags: python, windows, cuda, md5

Здравствуйте, у меня есть код :

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os,hashlib,mmap

hexchars={'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','a','b','c','d','e','f'}
fs=range(0,16)

RFILE='1.txt' # файл, откуда читать
DIR='/md5/' # папка, куда сохранять
def md5hash(txt):
    m = hashlib.md5()
    m.update(txt)
    return m.hexdigest()

with open(RFILE, "r+t") as f:
    fsize=os.stat(RFILE).st_size
    map1 = mmap.mmap(f.fileno(), 0)
    for i in hexchars:
        fs[int(i,16)]=open(DIR+i,'w+t')
    while True:
        line=map1.readline()
        if not line: break
        line=line.decode('cp1251')
        line=line.encode('utf8')
        line=line.rstrip("\r\n")
        #print line
        res=md5hash(line)
        #print res
        firstchar=res[0:1]
        #print firstchar
        fs[int(firstchar,16)].write(line.decode('utf8').encode('cp1251')+' '+res+"\n")
    map1.flush()
    map1.close()
```

Скрипт берет большой файл со словами типа :

```
abcd
abcde
abcdef
```

генерирует к каждому слову хеш формата MD5, и записывает все это в соответствующие файлы,
но делает он это очень медленно... система у меня вроде нормальная по характеристикам, записывает медленно в файлы... может быть можно как-то ускорить код? или может есть что-то наподобие этого скрипта, только на другом языке, более быстром.

> Система : Windows 7 (64bit)
>
> ОЗУ : 8гб DDR3 1333mhz (Dual channel)
>
> Проц : Intel® Core i3-2100

и еще возможно ли такой-же скрипт сделать на AMD Brook+ ? что бы на уровне GPU все выполнить?))

> Видеокарта : Sapphire HD 6770 (800 потоковых процессоров)

в barswf набирает 690мл паролей в секунду.

мне кажется на GPU если это возможно, будет быстрее...

Comment: Может, у вас все в скорость диска упирается?

Answer (score 3):

Задача, скорее всего ограничена скоростью жёсткого диска (I/O bound). Чтобы проверить, достаточно заменить decode/encode/md5hash вызовы на `lambda s: s` (функцию, которая возвращает её аргумент как есть) и посмотреть как это повлияет на время исполнения с холодным дисковым кэшом. Разница в производительности между данными, которые уже в памяти, и данными, которые необходимо считать с диска, [может достигать 10 раз](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25606833/fastest-way-to-sum-integers-in-text-file#comment40064167_25606833). Поэтому, применение GPU может не дать никаких результатов даже если бы результаты вычислялись бы мгновенно ([Закон Амдала](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%90%D0%BC%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0)).

Чтобы улучшить производительность ввода/вывода, можно использовать сжатые (`gzip.open()`) файлы и распаковывать их при чтении, и архивировать на лету при сохранении. Т.е. быстрый CPU используется, чтобы скомпенсировать медленный диск.

Можно попробовать уменьшить фрагментацию на диске, резервируя место на диске, используя аналог `fallocate()` для файлов, открытых на запись. `ctypes` модуль может вызвать `SetFilePointerEx(); SetEndOfFile()`, чтобы эмулировать `fallocate()`.

Можно попробовать поизменять размер буфера индивидуальных файлов и посмотреть влияет ли это на то как часто считывающим головкам жёсткого диска приходится прыгать с места на место из-за записи в несколько разных файлов одновременно. Хотя Операционная система и дисковый контроллеров могут самостоятельно менять порядок записи в разные файлы, чтобы уменьшить прыжки между трэками.

Можно попробовать избавиться от сохранения на диск совсем:

```
C:\> generate_words | hash_words | use_words_and_hashes
```

Если диск достаточно быстрый, например, если RAMDisk используется, то время исполнения задачи можно значительно ускорить, вычисляя хэши для блоков слов паралельно, [используя несколько потоков](https://gist.github.com/zed/f199d5a0c453be2e9681#file-sum1gints-ctypes-py) и даже GPU.

Дополнительную информацию можно найти в похожем вопросе на stackoverflow: [Is it possible to use the GPU to accelerate hashing in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047601/is-it-possible-to-use-the-gpu-to-accelerate-hashing-in-python) и обсуждение на reddit: [Is there a GPU backend for Numpy/Scipy? Money is no issue.](http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/1mw9mb/is_there_a_gpu_backend_for_numpyscipy_money_is_no/) -- резюме: питон может упростить управление ресурсами, но вычислительные GPU ядра всё равно придётся писать под конкретную задачу (хотя такие вещи как md5 можно уже готовые найти) т.е., (ожидаемо) нет автоматической компиляции произвольного Питон кода для исполнения на GPU.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно не стоит построчно читать и писать в файл
загружайте файл целиком, вычисляйте хэши и потом записывайте в файл все целиком, если файл на столько большой, что не помещается в RAM, то частями

Answer (score 0):

Сохраняйте на диск когда соберется определенное кол-во записей (допустим 1000), а не каждую. Перепишите все на си(скорость диска это не увеличит), не вызывайте дорогостоящий decode, encode. Перепишите все в асинхронном стиле, что-бы запись на диск не блокировала процесс. Пишите в едином стиле код (я про оформление). Про gpu к сожалению ничего сказать не могу, но библиотеки для этого дела есть.